# BoxInsetLayout cutting off text on round display

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I'm building a full screen wear app which is a combination of cards and other custom views. I extended `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` so that each screen is a fragment. In one of my fragments I'd like to display a card. It works fine on a square watch, but on a round one things get cut off.

I'm following the [Creating Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html) guide on google's site.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_card_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_box="bottom"/>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Then I inflate in my Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    CardFragment cardFragment = CardFragment.create(
      "Testing",
      "Testing some description"
    );
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_card_frame, cardFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return cardView;

}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: Wear Round Emulator]

Please note that I am setting `app:layout_box="bottom"` as well.
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is because the round devices dont have any screen-real estate down there. As you can see in this picture fx the bottom part is black.

[image: Moto 360]